# Navigation Drawer Active State not working

Tags: android

I think it is a simple problem but it makes me scratch my head.

I've been trying to make it work but I always fail. Please bear with my question.

Active state doesn't work on items that inside items>menu.

If I press the item. View is working perfectly. However, If I press the burger menu. The item is not having the active state and the last item with the active state will still be active.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_game"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_account"
        android:title="Game" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_livechat"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_account"
        android:title="Live Chat"/>
</group>

<item android:title="Transaction">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_deposit"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_depwit"
            android:title="Deposit" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_withdraw"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_depwit"
            android:title="Withdraw" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_transfer"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_transfer"
            android:title="Transfer" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_fragment, homeFragment, homeFragment.getTag()).commit();
    } else if () {
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to add addbackstack(null); in your fragment transaction, and in host activity override navigationclickLiatener

Comment: Just set  item.setChecked(true); inside every if ,else if ..condition .AND  android:checked="true" ,set it inside menu.xml  by default in <Home>  item

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
        MenuItem previousMenuItem;
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         if (previousMenuItem != null) {
                previousMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            }
            item.setChecked(true);
            previousMenuItem = item;
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_fragment, homeFragment, homeFragment.getTag()).commit();
        } else if () {
            // and so on...
        }
    }
```

Not a perfect solution but worked for me..

Comment: Thank you for the effort but this doesn't apply the full active state on item. Don't have the background and the previousMenuItem is not working.

Comment: @LaraBelle What you meant by full active state ? .The previousMenuItem  should be a global varible for this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I chose a wrong word. I just said it because it doesn't have the background. It's very hard to develop android app. :/

Comment: @LaraBelle oops my bad.. Check my edit..I didn't noticed your if condition .It's only for home click so writing inside that if condition dosen't wrk..Also Android is not that hard..I am self learned or learning..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet try it, Hope it'll help you

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    if (!item.isChecked()) {
        item.setChecked(true);
    }
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.nav_home:
         // Your action goes here....
         break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the use of mBundle?

Comment: If you wanna pass some data to another fragment, you can set those data  in bundle and then pass this bundle as argument while fragment transaction, but you don't need it actually so ignore that line......